# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, session, datetime, exception

I want to add a date in session (date1) like this:

```
Session["DateLesson"] = date1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Now from the session I want take this value:

```
var asd = Session["DateLesson"];
/*asd = "20.04.2012"*/
var datelesson = DateTime.Parse((string) asd);
```

And it gives me this exception:

> FormatException not recognized as a valid DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why persist your date as a string?

You could simply store it like this:

```
Session["DateLesson"] = date1;
```

And then retrieve it like this:

```
var datelesson = (DateTime)Session["DateLesson"];
```

Answer (score 4):

A period is not a valid/standard separator character in most locales. You'll need to use DateTime.ParseExact() in combination with a format string to tell the function how to read it. More importantly, if reading it back to a datetime is your main goal, why not just put the datetime in the session as is? That seems **way** more efficient, easier, and more maintainable to me.

Comment: This is not quite correct.  The period *is* the standard separator character for some locales (Russia, for example).  Whether using Parse or ParseExact, the OP would benefit from using an overload that accepts an `IFormatProvider` parameter.

Comment: @phoog - added some weasel words. happy?

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = "20.04.2012";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
```

This will return `4/20/2012 12:00:00:00 AM`

Comment: string value = Session["DateLesson"].ToString();
       DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);              String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep value as a string but as an object of the initial type:

```
public DateTime? DateLesson
{
    get
    {
        DateTime? dateTime = Session["DateLesson"] as DateTime?;
        if (dateTime.HasValue) // not null
        {
            // use dateTime.Value
        }
    }
    set
    {
        Session["DateLesson"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea - It seemed a reasonable solution to me given the details in the question, so I countered it.